# I am trying to use PDFbox on the IBM Domino server, getting NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jar, lotus-domino, pdfbox, ls2j

I can run my IBM Notes agent locally without error, however when I run the agent on the server I get the following error.

> LS2J Error: Threw java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument in procedure GETTEMPLATE, line 79

My **LotusScript** agent calls a java class using LS2J.
The java class using the following libraries:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
```

I have had the following JAR files added to to Domino server, and had it restarted.

```
pdfbox-1.8.jar,
commons-lang-2.1.jar,
commons-logging-1.2.jar
```

Are there other JAR files I need copied to: `\notes\jvm\lib\ext`
or is there something else wrong?

Comment: Have you read this?
https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/dependencies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [two ways](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_USING_LS2J.html) to get it to run on server:

- specify variable JavaUserClasses (or JavaUserClassesExt) in server's **notes.ini** like
  `JavaUserClasses=C:\...\jvm\lib\ext`
  and restart server *or*
- create a Script Library of type Java, import the jars as Archives and "use" the Script Library in Lotus Script code
  `Use "pdfBox"`

  [image]

Comment: I added the following jars (imported archive, then attached source) to my java script library (which also includes the java class I am using to process the PDFs)      **commons-logging-1.2.jar,   fontbox-1.8.8.jar and pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar**.    however now I get a different error..              '**Agent  error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font (initialization failure)**'

Comment: You have to include **pdfbox-1.8.9.jar** (probably instead of pdfbox-app-1.8.9.jar)

Comment: I added the jar files, including  pdfbox-1.8.9. jar to the web-inf/lib folder in the .NSF. then right clicked them and to add them to the build path.  I am getting error **LS2J Error: Threw java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument**

Comment: You have to add pdfbox-1.8.9.jar to Java Scriptlibrary's Archive section like shown in picture above.

Comment: BTW web-inf/lib folder is ignored by Java agents (or LotusScript agents calling Java parts by LS2J). It's only used by XPages Java code.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann same problem here, with pdfbox-2.0.25 and fontbox-2.0.25 (and commons-logging). What am I missing?

Comment: This seems related: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/fontbox/2.0.14